# How to add buttons and inputs in a wordpress.com site

Tags: html, wordpress

I added a custom html block on my wordpress.com site and wrote a simple bit of code to act as a search widget.

I've tried many things. I tried making button run a script function, I tried making the function listen for the button, I tried using a a href link (maybe woud work if I tried harder).

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="Search...">
<br>
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://vinelings.home.blog/?s=' + document.getElementById('input').value"> Search</button>
```

I want it to make the button grab the input text then redirect the tab the search for that term.
Not sure if this is a wordpress.com problem, if it is can i get around it in any way?

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sefaa.png
Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu9CH.png

**EDIT:**
I am using the `Custom HTML` block.
My theme is ALtoFocus.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to put your html markup into `custom html` block

Comment: That's what I've been using. BTW My theme is AltoFocus.